# Angular Material Radio Button does not show selected value after reset

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a radio group which I have set up in a form. You can change the radio groups value by clicking on a radio button, or by changing the select controls value.

The issue:

When I use the reset (or setValue/patchValue) on the radio button control it will uncheck the selection so that no buttons are selected if the current selected value is the same as the value I am resetting it to.

How to replicate:

I made a [stack blitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-radio-checked-bug)

If you go there, the radio control is initialized as "one, one" being selected. You can change the value of the radio control by clicking on a different button. And then you can reset the value by hitting the reset button. The form correctly reverts back to having "one, one" selected. However, if you press the reset button again (or if you press the reset button without changing the initial value)... the form will change the radio buttons so that non are checked.

The backing model data for the control is the correct value ([1, 1]) and the method I use to determine if a button should be checked is valid and returns true for the correct button but for some reason the button will not show as checked.

The only work around I have found is to block resetting the value if the radio control is already set to the default value, but in my current use case this work around is not easily implemented because I am using nested FormGroups and when I reset the form I don't have easy access to the controls value.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, if I set local variable v up to pass the parameter of v.data to FormControl, it works:

```
resetValue(event: Event) {
  var v = { data : [1,1] };
  this.formControl.reset(v.data);
}
```

And then when I checked a little closer, it's because the reset() function was setting the formControl values to an array containing 1 and 1, opposed to a single value with an array of [1,1].

[Console output of FormControl object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrJa5.png)

Comment: Im confused. There is no difference between what you did and what i did. If `a=1` and `b.v=1` then `a==b.v`. It wouldn't make a difference if I set the form control to `a` or `b.v`. I still tired it though and it gave the same [result](https://stackblitz.com/edit/feg4id?file=app/radio-ng-model-example.ts). As for the value of the formControl... it does set it to an array containing 1 and 1. I don't see how that is different from setting it to a single value with an array of [1,1], again these mean the same thing. Unless I'm still missing something?

Answer (score 0):

even this is an old topic I just found a solution:

**HTML part**

```
<mat-radio-group aria-labelledby="Rolle" [formControl]="rolesControl" class="role-radio-group">
  <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let userRoles of ALL_USER_ROLES"
                      class="role-radio-button {{isSame(userRoles) ? 'mat-radio-checked' : ''}}"
                      [checked]="isSame(userRoles)"
                      [value]="userRoles">{{userRoleAsText(userRoles)}}</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

**TS part**

```
public reset(): void {
  this.myGroup.reset(this.myData);
}
```

**Problem description**

The selection itself is working. But the css class will not be set...
[image]

When the class is added, you will also the radio button highlighted :-)

[image]